# How do I read response of BaseHttpActionResult containing Datetime type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I received a code in C# of Client-Service with HTTP protocol.
I needed to add a new action who returns `Datetime` type, so from what I found online (not sure that what I did is correct) I expanded an already existing `BaseHttpActionResult` class:

```
public BaseHttpActionResult(HttpStatusCode code, DateTime content)
{
    _code = code;
    _content = content;
}

public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        StatusCode = _code,
        Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(DateTime), _content, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
    };

    return Task.FromResult(response);
}
```

the service add this action:

```
[Route("StatusUpdate")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult StatusUpdate()
{
    return new BaseHttpActionResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, DateTime.Today);
}
```

and the client request:

```
public class HttpRequestsHandler
{
    public static DateTime HttpGet(string requestUrl)
    {
        using (var handler = new WebRequestHandler())
        {
            handler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler)
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(requestUrl),
                Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan
            })
            {
                using (var response = httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl).Result)
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        var errorMessage = string.Format("HttpRequestTask: Request failed with status {0} for URL: {1}", response.StatusCode, requestUrl);
                        throw new HttpException(errorMessage, (int)response.StatusCode);
                    }
                    response.???????
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is, how do I read the `Datetime` value from the response?
I saw online that there's methods named Content and Headers and a few examples, but I failed to understand how to use it...

Would appreciate any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over complicating things. If all you have to return is that date time from the web api end point then use existing functionality

```
[Route("StatusUpdate")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult StatusUpdate() {
    return Ok(DateTime.Today);
}
```

As for getting response use the available extension methods to convert the response to the type you want.

```
var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<DateTime>().Result;
return result;
```

Should consider using strongly typed model.

```
public class StatusUpdateResponse {
    public DataTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

which results in updating action to ...

```
[Route("StatusUpdate")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult StatusUpdate() {
    return Ok(new StatusUpdateResponse { Timestamp = DateTime.Today });
}
```

and

```
var model = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<StatusUpdateResponse>().Result
return model.Timestamp;
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, Much obliged!